# How do I add a user to a group

Tags: debian, users, raspbian, group

How do I add a user to a group.

This is on a system with no `root` password and only a single user `pi` with `sudo` privileges.

`usermod` seems to have been designed to make this as difficult as possible.

Comment: `usermod -a -G groupname username` doesn't work on raspbian?

Comment: @jimmij I think I was missing the `-a` I was going from a book on Ubuntu which said `-G` didn't work if the user is logged in, and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Without `-a` groups are overwritten, this is most of the time not what you want to do, unless you create new user.

Comment: you use -G when adding new user and want it to be a member of supplementary group along with primary group , otherwise you can use usermod with -aG

Comment: The `usermod` works whether the user is logged in or not, however it only affects _new_ sessions; current sessions don't pick up the change.  So after the `usermod` you should logout and login again.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `usermod` or edit the group file directly

```
# usermod -a -G ${group} ${user}

# vi /etc/group
...
wheel:x:10:root,user1,user2
...
```

Just remember group changes do not always propagate to active sessions. If you are changing a user who is currently logged in (including yourself), they must logout and login again for the change to take effect. (Under some circumstances a reboot may be required. Check `id` after logging in again to see if the new group is present.)

Comment: I had to use `-G` flag instead of `G` alone